# How to load only newly added record into datagridview?

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I am developing the windows application in VS 2010

I am binding the data to grid using generic collection.

Here is the code

```
Private sub LoadAllCustomer()
Dim oCustomerCollection as new Customers
oCustomers.LoadAll() //Loads all the collection of customers
gvCustomerGrid.DataSource = oCustomerCollection 
End sub
```

Above code work fine...
I have details form which saved the data into customer table in DB. When I save the record , I just want to add new row into grid contains recently added record.

(Previously, I was using Devexpress's grid's RefeshDataSource property. 
 but now I am using Visual Studio's grid which don't have this property.)

Is there any way for it ? Or I have to load entire data into grid again to show recently added record  ?

Comment: You should show the type of "Customers". You can use a `BindingSource` (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource(v=vs.110).aspx) to allow the DGV to understand your updates depending on your source collection type.

Comment: Create a call to the database and refill the customers collection with the new updated data then rebind it to the grid